# substract timediff from time value

Tags: mysql, time, difference

This is my table:

```
    +----------+---------------------+
    | estimate | timestamp           |
    +----------+---------------------+
    | 05:00:00 | 2015-12-02 13:35:14 |
    +----------+---------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am trying to implement a scheduled job to create extra automatic rows every hour to substract the time that has past from the estimated time.

I am able to start the scheduled job and use timediff to calculate the time that has passed since, but i am unable to substract the timediff from the estimated time.

I am guessing that mysql doesn't care much that i want the estimated time column to be stated as a period of time. instead, it just shows me a time without the date.

```
select timediff(now(),timestamp) from t1;
```

this gives me the time difference that i need:

```
    +---------------------------+
    | timediff(now(),timestamp) |
    +---------------------------+
    | 00:27:03                  |
    +---------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but when i do this:

```
     select estimate-timediff(now(),timestamp) as timeleft from t1;
```

the result is:

```
    +----------+
    | timeleft |
    +----------+
    |    46568 |
    +----------+
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

what i would like to get:

```
    +----------+
    | timeleft |
    +----------+
    | 04:32:57 |
    +----------+
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

The times may be a little off in my example obviously because of the timediff() but hopefully you understand my issue. There must be an easy solution that i'm missing but i've spent half a day googleing to get to this point but timediff just won't cut me some slack.

Please and thank you!

PS. I haven't found the solution yet but i think i found what might cause the problem. Obvioysly the substraction is done by using absolute values 'estimate' column doesn't use seconds as it's absolute value and the result is completely wrong.

```
    mysql> select abs(estimate) from t1;
    +----------+
    | abs(estimate) |
    +----------+
    |    50000 |
    +----------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
    mysql> select abs(timediff(now(),timestamp)) from t1;
    +--------------------------------+
    | abs(timediff(now(),timestamp)) |
    +--------------------------------+
    |                           2318 |
    +--------------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So is there an easy way to force mysql to use seconds on a time column? or is something wrong with my table and the estimate format is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `timediff` like that :-

```
timediff(estimate,timediff(now(),timestamp))
```

your query :-

```
select timediff(estimate,timediff(now(),timestamp)) 
as timeleft from t1;
```

Comment: thanks Rahautos, you can remove other comments ( i removed mine already. then i can upvote and aprove this solution. with your help i came out with this solution: `mysql> select *,timediff(now(),timestamp),sec_to_time(time_to_sec(estimate)-time_to_sec(timediff(now(),timestamp))) from t1;` but this is rather long and stupid. `select timediff(estimate,timediff(now(),timestamp)) 
as timeleft from t1;` works brilliantly and is an easy solution i was looking for...

Comment: if only i could lose the fractions now... the result will be on this format: `04:10:42.000` but i would like it to be like this: `04:10:42`.... but it doesn't matter as i can just ignore them with a select..